# C# WPF Gmail Sign and Count Emails

Tags: c#, wpf, email, smtp, gmail

Hello i need count message through pop3 from gmail. And I have this code.

```
public int MessageCount
        {
            get
            {
                sWriter.WriteLine("stat");
                sWriter.Flush();
                string[] splitResponse = GetResponse().Split(' ');
                return Convert.ToInt32(splitResponse[1]);
            }
        }
```

Error: A first chance exception of type 'System.IndexOutOfRangeException' occurred in ImapDemo.exe
Can you help ?

Answer (score 0):

Your array does not contain the index that you're searching for. You can simply check that it exists before attempting to use it. I'm not sure why you're looking at the second item in the array for the email count though.

```
            if(splitResponse.length > 1) return Convert.ToInt32(splitResponse[1]);
            else return -1;//or indicate a failure some other way
```